# Problem in binary tree; need help

Tags: java

can you help me please?  I am making a binary tree with node insertion.  How can I insert the new node to the current node in respect of BST rule?

Example: first the root is empty.

Input number: 50

This will display "Success!"

Insert number: 40

Successfully inserted in the left subtree of 50

insert number: 20

successfully inserted in the left subtree of 40

insert number: 80

successfully inserted in the right subtree of 50

Can you help me please? Thank you in advance hoping for your positive response...

Here's my code:

```
class Node
{
  public int num;
  public Node llink;
  public Node rlink;
}


public class BinaryTreeOperations
{
  //public Node llink=null;
  // public Node rlink=null;
  private Node temp;
  private Node current;
  private Node root;

  public boolean isEmpty()
  {
    return root==null;
  }


  public void insertNum(int n)
  {

    temp=null;
    current=null;  


    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.num=n;
    newNode.llink=null;
    newNode.rlink=null;


    if(isEmpty())
    {
      root=newNode;
      System.out.println("Successfully inserted!");
    }
    else
    {
      temp=root;
      while(temp!=null)
      {
        current = temp;
        root = current;
        temp=null; 
      }

    if(n<current.num)
    {
      current.llink=newNode;
      //current.llink=temp;
      System.out.println("inserted on the left subtree " +current.num);
    }  
    else
    {
      newNode.rlink=newNode; 
      System.out.println("inserted on the right subtree  "+current.num );
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Also: what is wrong with your code so far?

Comment: hello thanks for the reply.i'm a newbie here i apologize if i get wrong in posting...it's homework

Comment: @jemz, no worries, this community likes to tag homework as homework so that prospective answers can provide more explanation than just code alone. That is one of the great things about the SO community, people here genuinely want to help with comprehension not just completion.

Comment: With homework problems I like to just point out problems in the code -- half the time students have gone blind staring at their code trying to _find_ the problem, and that's frequently unproductive -- but once the problem has been found, can start working on _fixing_ the problem, which often _is_ productive.

Comment: i can't track the the current node the above output is what i want to be happen..but in my code it's not

Comment: can you help me sir how can i insert the new node into the current node so that i cant get the right output like the above i posted

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop seems wrong. What you really want to do is start at the root and traverse the tree until you reach the node which will serve as the parent of your new node. Below you are not doing any traversal or inspection to find where the new node should go. That is what you really need to be doing.

```
while(temp!=null) {
    current = temp;
    root = current;
    temp=null; 
}
```

Should be something like this:

```
while(parent not found) {
    if (new node is smaller than current) {
        if (current has left child) {
            assign left child to current and loop
        } else {
            make current the parent of the new node
        }
    } else {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: sir i am confuse of this if(current has left child) can you help me on this sir i really don't know can you show the code sir please?

Comment: It is intentionally written in pseudocode since this is a homework question :)

Comment: @ryanprayogo sir thank you for the reply just to clarify if(current==current.llink)is this what he meant?

Comment: @ryanprayogo yes sir i understand this is a homework but i have 2 days to submit this exercise in our school...i really need your help sir...

Comment: @jemz binary tree nodes have at most two children. A left child and a right child. If we were to ask ourselves "Does a node have a left child?" we would check the pointer to the left child for a non-null value. In code that would be `current.llink != null`.

Comment: @TimBender, Sir thank you i will write again if i have doubt...question, sir if i am going to post my code after i edit my code.the button below which is add another answer is that were i am going to post my new edited code so that i can show you?

Comment: @TimBender, Sir Kindly look at my code if i got the correct answer...Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> else
>   {
>    temp=root;
>    while(temp!=null)
>    {
>       current = temp;
>       root = current;
>       temp=null;
>    }
> ```

This loop will only ever run once. Probably not what you intended. :)

> ```
> if(n<current.num)
> {
>   current.llink=newNode;
>   //current.llink=temp;
>   System.out.println("inserted on the left subtree " +current.num);
> }
> else
> {
>   newNode.rlink=newNode;
>   System.out.println("inserted on the right subtree  "+current.num );
> }
> ```

In one branch you are assigning to `current.llink`, in the other branch you are assigning to `newNode.rlink`. Oops. :)

Comment: okay thenk sir i will post again im going to edit my code...thank you sir

Comment: sir i am confuse how can i code this if (current has left child) {
            assign left child to current and loop

Comment: and also sir how i can put my code in posting like you did in your answer sir

Comment: @jemz, edit your own post, and put in your code; it formats nicely if you add four spaces before every line. (If that is too hard with your text editor, just leave it, and I'm sure someone else can fix it up in a few seconds.)

Answer (score 0):

Your methodology for adding to the binary search tree seems incorrect.

You need to read up on Binary Search Trees to figure out how you will maintain the structure of your tree.

Below is some code that shows how to add to a Binary Search Tree, but I define a tree as empty if it contains no data.

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return data == null;
}
```

The rest of the code is pretty self explanatory and should help you figure out how to add to the tree to maintain order.

```
public boolean add(Comparable target) {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        setData(target);
        this.setLeftTree(new BinarySearchTree());
        this.setRightTree(new BinarySearchTree());
        return true;
    } else {
        int comparison = getData().compareTo(target);
        if(comparison == 0)
            return false;
        else {
            if(comparison < 0) {
                return getRightTree().add(target);
            } else {
                return getLeftTree().add(target);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: sir can you please help for my code because that what my teacher wants he give the psuedocode.then we will just supply the code.Please help me thank you in advance hoping for your positive response